# Wait for event from SqlListener

Tags: c#, events, wait

I have implemented a SqlListener class that uses SqlDependency to wait for changes in SQL database. At one point in my business workflow I need to wait for a record turning up in the database. The SqlListener triggers an event when requested record is found. This works fine. I can make it work by entering a While-loop and wait until I detect the event being returned. But this is not ideal design. It makes the processor spin a lot in vain.

I would like to wait for the event in a more intelligent manner. I read a lot of suggestions on using Task, NotificationDelegate, ManualResetEvent, etc. .... but I was not able to get it all together.

A simplified example will probably make it easier to understand. This is my current setup that works. But if possible I would like to get rid of the ugly while loop.

```
private const int MaxWaitTime = 5;
private SqlListener<RecordType> _recordListener;
private RecordType _record;

/// <summary>
/// Request a record and wait until it is found.
/// </summary>
public RecordType GetRecordAwait(int requestedId)
{
    // Initiate listening for record
    _recordListener = new SqlListener<RecordType>();
    _recordListener.SqlModified += SqlListener_SqlModified;
    _recordListener.StartListening(requestedId);

    // Wait until record is found
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    while (_record == null && 
                 DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds < MaxWaitTime)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    // Stop listening
    _recordListener.SqlModified -= SqlListener_SqlModified;
    _recordListener.Dispose();
    _recordListener = null;

    // Return record
    return _record;
}

private void SqlListener_SqlModified(object sender, SqlModifiedArgs args)
{
    _record = (RecordType)args.Record;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the solution was more simple than I first thought. When I rephrased my question and searched again I found it. The ManualResetEvent as mentioned already in my question turned out to be the simplest way to solve it.

All I had to do was to add a ManualResetEvent and set it to wait ;-)

```
    private const int MaxWaitTime = 5000;
    private SqlListener<RecordType> _recordListener;
    private RecordType _record;
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _recordWaiter = new ManualResetEvent(false);


    /// <summary>
    /// Request a record and wait until it is found.
    /// </summary>
    public RecordType GetRecordAwait(int requestedId)
    {
        // Initiate listening for record
        _recordListener = new SqlListener<RecordType>();
        _recordListener.SqlModified += SqlListener_SqlModified;
        _recordListener.StartListening(requestedId);

        // Wait synchronously until record is found
        _recordWaiter.WaitOne(MaxWaitTime);

        // Stop listening
        _recordListener.SqlModified -= SqlListener_SqlModified;
        _recordListener.Dispose();
        _recordListener = null;

        // Return record
        return _record;
    }

    private void SqlListener_SqlModified(object sender, SqlModifiedArgs args)
    {
        _record = (RecordType)args.Record;
        _recordWaiter.Set();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using While, you could go with Timer and events. Something like:

```
public class ListenerWaiting
{
    public ListenerWaiting(int waitingTimeSeconds)
    {
        _waitSeconds = waitingTimeSeconds;
    }

    private int _waitSeconds;
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private Listener _listener;

    public event EventHandler<string> ListenerDone;

    public void Listen(int listeningPeriodSeconds)
    {
        _listener = new Listener(listeningPeriodSeconds * 1000);
        _listener.ListenerCompleted += ListenerListenerCompleted;
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(_waitSeconds * 1000) {Enabled = true};
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
    }

    void ListenerListenerCompleted(object sender, string e)
    {
        StopTimer();
        StopListener();
        if (ListenerDone != null)
            ListenerDone(this, "Waiting success! Message was: " + e);
    }

    void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        StopTimer();
        StopListener();
        if (ListenerDone != null)
            ListenerDone(this, "Waited longer than set, aborted waiting...");
    }

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Elapsed -= TimerElapsed;
        _timer = null;
    }

    private void StopListener()
    {
        _listener.ListenerCompleted -= ListenerListenerCompleted;
        _listener = null;
    }
}

public class Listener
{
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private string _listeningPeriodSeconds;
    public event EventHandler<string> ListenerCompleted;

    public Listener(int listeningPeriodSeconds)
    {
        _listeningPeriodSeconds = listeningPeriodSeconds.ToString();
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(listeningPeriodSeconds) { Enabled = true };
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
    }

    private void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Elapsed -= TimerElapsed;
        _timer = null;
        if (ListenerCompleted != null)
            ListenerCompleted(this, _listeningPeriodSeconds);
    }

}
```

...and then consume it with:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wait = new ListenerWaiting(5);
        wait.ListenerDone += WaitListenerDone;

        wait.Listen(3);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void WaitListenerDone(object sender, string e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
```

I guess I could find better names for classes, but you'll get the idea ;)

Comment: Thanks for your concern, but your suggestion makes me confused. Is this really a solution to my question? My stumbling block was to wait for an event in a "synchronous way". I understand I can add a timer to wait instead of the while looping but both timer result and event result will still turn up in the event handler WaitListenerDone. How will this help me to then continue in the consecutive workflow of the main method?